# Chances for rolling the "Bow Attacks fire an additional Arrow" on a bow

Tags: path-of-exile

I have a shaper influenced thicket bow base. I've used almost 2000 alts on it but I never gotten the "Bow Attacks fire an additional Arrow" mod, which is a suffix of splintering.

I'm pretty sure I've rolled into all other possible mods on the bow by now, so I'm wondering what the chances are rolling that mod? Or is there any preconditions that I haven't met which would result in me not getting the mod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Suffix* **Bow Attacks fire an additional Arrow** *(of Splintering)*
Requires [Item Level](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Item_level) 86

Any Bow with Item level 86 or higher can roll that modifier as a suffix. You don't need a shaper one, but a shaper influeced can roll that modifier. Check your item level, probably it's lower than 86. Otherwise, it's just bad luck.

Comment: ...I've just looked up thicket bows they are of item level 56. however, i've seen thicket bows with that mod on trade site. so how come those thicket bows have that mod?

Comment: @Will Thicket bows *are not* item level 56, that is the minimum required level for you to equip one and has nothing to do with what mods can roll. Item level is based on the level of the zone an item drops in and the rarity of the monster. Item level 86 items will *only* come from bosses in level 84 zones. T16 maps are level 83, so at best you can only get level 85 items from the bosses. You will need to fight shaper himself or uber elder to get a shaped thicket bow

Comment: @VanBuzzKill gotcha. it looks like i still have a lot to learn in this game. appreciate your comment.

Comment: @Will  there are simpler ways to get ilevel 86 items than fighting Shaper himself, you can also get them from strongboxes with the +# chest level as well as some unique  watchstones that increase the levels of monsters in the region (there are 3 different ones that work) as well as the abyssal depths which also increase the ilevel. Though you could also just buy the required bow base if you are interested in crafting it yourself

Comment: @KaranShishoo Thanks! I ended up buying lvl 86 items for crafting.